70s/80s horror/thriller about a man’s escape from a demon-possessed town until he hitchhikes with possessed riders heading back to the same town
I saw this film when I was around 7 years old and would like to see it again, but I can't think of the name of it.
I was young, so I don't remember many details, but it was about a man trying to escape a town full of demonic-possessed people. I think their eyes either glowed or they had none at all. At the very end of the film, the man escapes to a road and flags a car down with two people in it; he hitches a ride with them.
The film ends when they take the same exit to the town he just escaped from. When he says, "Don't go there," they both turn to him, and you can see their possessed eyes.
I believe the movie ends after that. I was very young when I saw this some 3 decades ago, not sure if it was from a movie or TV show.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

No offense, but we'd have more luck guessing what number between 1 and 10 you're thinking of. Try reading this help section for guidance on how to ask Identify-this-X questions. Ideally, we would have plot details, descriptions (characters/locations), where you watched it, when you watched it, how old it was, country of origin, animated or not, distinctive details, and ideas to rule out (e.g. definitely NOT Friday the 13th) at least to some degree, to help us help you.

That was it! "The Monster Club"(1981). Thank you so much!

@the guest OP has confirmed it, you should post an answer.

@theguest You should answer this.

The Monster Club (1981)
According to a comment by user43097 from 2017 (whose account has since been deleted), the film you’re describing is The Monster Club (1981). It’s an anthology film consisting of three separate stories, and the one you’re referring to is the third and final segment, titled "The Ghouls." In this segment, the ghouls don’t have glowing eyes, but the overall atmosphere and the plot align with your description.

A movie director scouting locations for his next film pays a horrifying visit to an isolated, decrepit village, Loughville, where the sinister residents refuse to let him leave. He discovers to his horror that the village is inhabited by species of corpse-eating demons called ghouls who unearth graves for food and clothes. And now there are no more graves to plunder, and the ghouls are hungry for flesh. While imprisoned by the ghouls, he meets Luna, the daughter of a ghoul father and a deceased human mother, making her a Hum-ghoul. Luna advises him to hide in the church, as ghouls cannot cross holy ground. Whilst in the church, the director discovers the terrifying truth of Loughville; centuries before, a swarm of ghouls invaded the village, mated with the humans, and made their nest there. With the aid of Luna, the director attempts to escape and almost succeeds – only for Luna to be killed by the ghouls and the director captured again and returned to the village by ghoul policemen.

